# What is difference between repo_upgrade and package_upgrade and apt_upgrade on cloud-init?

Tags: cloud-init

In an example from [AWS EC2 manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-cloud-init) shows that we can perform apt update and upgrade by putting:

```
repo_update: true
repo_upgrade: true
```

But I can't find exactly same commands in [cloud-init official documentation](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html), so I keep looking for the similiar commands and [found this](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#package-update-upgrade-install), they give two commands `package_upgrade` and `apt_upgrade` but didn't tell the difference.

It makes me curious that what's the difference between `repo_upgrade` and `package_upgrade` and `apt_upgrade`

Answer (score 5):

Yes this is quite puzzling, until I stumbled upon [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html#amazon-linux-cloud-init), from which it seems that `repo_upgrade` applies to Amazon Linux only.

Also I found this ancient fan-made [example](https://github.com/lovelysystems/cloud-init/blob/master/doc/examples/cloud-config-amzn.txt).

It seems that most of the explanations are correct.

Answer (score 2):

What I managed to find is

[repo_upgrade description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWM33.png)

(the source is **Security updates** section of [Package repository](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html#package-repository) topic - the official AWS Documentation)

**package_update**: (boolean) Set true to update packages. Happens before upgrade or install. Default: false.
**package_upgrade**: (boolean) Set true to upgrade packages. Happens before install. Default: false.
**apt_update**: (boolean) DEPRECATED: Dropped after April 2027. Use package_update. Default: false.
**apt_upgrade**: (boolean) DEPRECATED: Dropped after April 2027. Use package_upgrade. Default: false.
(see more details [here](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#package-update-upgrade-install))